# Javascript Global Variable for Cef Extension Scripts

Tags: javascript, c#, google-chrome-extension, chromium, cefsharp

First of all, I have searched in gitter and github discussion boards and wiki pages but still has no move..

So I ask the question for the first time here.....:

The last and may be the best thing is I tried that exposing an object to javascript scope.
https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/wiki/Frequently-asked-questions#Expose_dotNET

Okay this is working for string type objects. But I have a complex object that has several string arrays inside.

I want to keep javascript variable , lets call it var _myFilters values during the browsers lifecycle.

I know about cef extensions, there I remember this sentence:

> Extensions Extensions are like window bindings except they are loaded
>   into the context for every frame and cannot be modified once loaded.
>   The DOM does not exist when an extension is loaded and attempts to
>   access the DOM during extension loading will result in a crash.
>   Extensions are registered using the CefRegisterExtension() function
>   which should be called from the
>   CefRenderProcessHandler::OnWebKitInitialized() method.

quoting from a website :https://bitbucket.org/chromiumembedded/cef/wiki/JavaScriptIntegration

So I see this the best place where I can create my global javascript variable "_myFilters". It should be accesible in each browser tab, but I tried it , and saw it ( refer: " _myFilters " ) looses  value on each time page reloads.

Registering the object is an option but it does **not** fit well to my complex javascript object (_myFilters) ..

```
browser.RegisterJsObject("bound", new BoundObject());
```

This I tried but only worked well for string, int etc.

I am planning to expose an "object" (refer: _myFilters) data type but this time, the browser crashes.

**So the question is that:, what is the best way to have a global variable to be used in the files that are executing javascript files on browser loadstart, load end, on beforebrowse methods.. ?**

ps: I want this because, creating this _myFilters object is a job that takes some time (about 3 seconds). I want to have its values in my global value, so I can use it during browsers life cycle.

ps2: The type of _myFilters

[image]

Answer (score 1):

1. If you want your variables can be stored even when the browser process terminated, then I would suggest you use storage api like [chrome.storage](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/storage).
2. If the global variable just need to be maintained through the life of the browser process, I think you can set a variable in [background page](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/background_pages)

   > It exists for the lifetime of your extension, and only one instance of it at a time active.
3. And another choice is to use [Event Pages](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/event_pages). It is similar to background page, just set `persistent` `false` in manifest.json.

   > Event pages are loaded only when they are needed. When the event page is not actively doing something, it is unloaded, freeing memory and other system resources.

   Then you can also declare your global variables in event pages, add listen to [runtime.onSuspend](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/runtime#event-onSuspend) to store the state of the global variables using `chrome.storage.local.get()` when event page is about to unload. And also listen to other event handlers when event page is loaded, which depends on your need, may be [browserAction.onClicked](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/browserAction#event-onClicked) or [runtime.onMessage](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/runtime#event-onMessage), restore the global variable state using `chrome.storage.local.set()`

Comment: you are very good at this approach. I want to make this capabilities avaliable in chromimum based browser (cefsharp) . I mean I dont have this method . chrome.storage.local.set().. That is because I have shared many details about cef before my question.